# Python logging module not writing when run in cron

Tags: python, logging, cron

I am relatively new to linux so hopefully this is simple, though I cannot find the answer via search.
I am using cron (Debian Jessie on Raspberry pi) to run a script at 1 am every day which sleeps for some random amount of time less than a day and then runs another script. It is working just fine, but I am also trying to implement a log so that I can see a list of what times the script ran and also note if it did not start on time. When I run the script manually the log writes just fine, but when I let it be triggered through cron, no logs are created. Does anyone have any advice? The code follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from random import randint
import os
from time import sleep
import logging
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

time = now.hour*3600 + now.minute*60 + now.second # current time in seconds

logging.basicConfig(filename='script.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

sleep_time = randint(0,70000)

total_sec = sleep_time + time
hours = total_sec/3600
minutes = (total_sec%3600)/60
seconds = total_sec%60
if minutes < 10:
    minutes = "0" + str(minutes)
if seconds < 10:
    seconds = "0" + str(seconds)


logging.info(" Job started at " + str(now) + ". Will sleep for " + str(sleep_time) + " seconds. Script will begin at " + str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds) + ".")

if time < 3500 or time > 3700:
    logging.warning(" Script did not start at specified time. Script began at " + str(now))

sleep(sleep_time)
os.system("/path/to/program.py")
```

Comment: When this is triggered via cron with the logging statements included, does the script otherwise run just fine?  I would suggest making the `filename` argument in basicConfig an absolute path.  cron does not run from your home directory, so it could be as simple as that.

Comment: Try specifying the full log path instead of just the filename.

Comment: Thanks, the script does run just fine when triggered via cron except that it just doesn't log. I tried changing the filename argument to the absolute path and hopefully that will make it work! If that is the issue, then maybe the log file is sitting somewhere else...?

Comment: Yes, it probably is just sitting somewhere.  The rest of the script wouldn't run if you ran into a write permission error or something.  And it looks like I was mistaken, running cron does run from the user's home directory.  So check if `~/script.log` exists.  It does not run from the directory /path/to/program.py is in which is where you were probably expecting script.log to show up.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you both. Where is the working directory for "root" cron? The script runs from sudo crontab so then there might be a full log file somewhere on my system from the last few weeks.

Comment: Nevermind, it's in /root. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: im having the same issue at the moment, cron job works fine with the pytohn scrypt but does not log the one that uses flock, why would it be?